# シャットダウン (再起動) 時、VirtualBox Interface が起動中とあるが、どこにも表示されない。

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox

シャットダウン (再起動) 時、VirtualBox Interface が起動中 (Has active connection) とあるのですが、タスクマネージャーやタスクビューを見ても表示されません。毎回強制的にシャットダウン (再起動) してしまっているのですが、これはどこから表示、操作できるのでしょうか。

VirtualBox は毎回 (vagrant: PuTTY でも PowerShell でも) exit とコマンドを入力して閉じています。

**環境**
OS: Windows 10

Comment: インストールするとついてくるGUIのVirtualboxマネージャーでも仮想マシンは起動していないですか？

Comment: すみません、vagrant suspend を忘れていたからかもしれません、、、

Comment: シャットダウンはホスト OS 、ゲスト OS どちらに対しての操作ですか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtualboxではheadlessモードが存在して画面上は起動していなくて裏で起動する設定ができます。
https://qiita.com/byuu/items/840e4cee6babcf5b720b

コメントを見るとVagrantを利用しているようですが、デフォルトでHeadlessモードがOnになっており、裏でサーバが起動します。
https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/providers/virtualbox/configuration

またSSHにおけるexitはあくまでログアウトを実行するコマンドで仮想マシン自体は起動したままです。
マシンをシャットダウンするためには

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

を実行するか
ホスト側（VirtualboxやVagrantコマンドで）で強制停止や一時停止をするとよいでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox を閉じる際に、Power Shell で vagrant suspend を忘れ（、exit す）るとこのようになります。